# Difference in network utilization between single and multiple TCP connections

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, throughput

We know that the way (basic) TCP works is by starting with slow-start phase followed by a linear increase of congestion window (CWD). The CWD is adjusted according to network status. So once we initiate a connection, it will take some time for the connection to reach a stable CWD, depending on the network condition.

So, by this logic, a TCP connection will try to fill all the available b/w of a link. So, if there are multiple TCP connections, each will adjust their CWD so that there is minimal congestion.

So suppose I have a 100 Mbps link (The topology is given below)
I have an application which is sending UDP traffic
I have another application `iperf` which can initiate parallel TCP connections along that same link

```
[h1] ---- 100 Mbps ---- [h2]

h1 (UDP + iperf client)
h2 (UDP + iperf server)
```

I'm doing an experiment in the following manner

1. 1 UDP + 1 TCP
2. 1 UDP + 2 TCP
3. 1 UDP + 4 TCP
4. 1 UDP + 8 TCP and so on

My finding says that the throughput of 1 TCP connection is lower than the throughput of 8 TCP connections combined (Exp 1 vs Exp 4). It should be kept in mind that the individual throughput of the 8 connections is much lower (which is obvious).

So my question is, **why can't the single TCP connection utilize the full b/w that the 8 TCP can do together?**

Comment: You didn't add details how you used `iperf`, but guessing: 8 TCP connections cause more UDP packets to be dropped than 1 TCP connection, so the one UDP gets less bandwidth, so the total bandwidth used of 8 TCP connections is higher. First thing I'd do is measure how many UDP packets are dropped in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using CUBIC or another AIMD congestion control algorithm, when it hits congestion it quickly drops its rate back a bit and then slowly ramps it back up to find the max again. This leaves little “scallops” (in a tcptrace graph) of unused bandwidth that other flows can fill. If the UDP flow is fixed-rate, it won’t fill those gaps. But other competing TCP flows certainly will. I suspect the more TCP flows you have, the more they’ll fill in any bandwidth left by the others’ congestion control measures.